# grpc header/cookie in Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to do place on server application which can be called by Go APP and Java app both.

for some reason ,there's a cookie authentication and oAuth mechanism ,so I want to set one Go app as  Auth Micro-service for the authentication purpose.

As GRPC is built on the HTTP2 ,so The headers and cookies are on the protocol.but I did not find out how to carry on header and cookie when the rpc occurs,implemented by Go, on GitHub I only found the JAVA-Implementation for headers at :

```
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/header
```

Can anybody give me some direction of Go implementation for this purpose?

Comment: Shameless plug: support for cookies in gRPC **Java** implemented as a custom `ClientInterceptor`.
Cookies are managed by inspecting set-cookie HTTP headers received in the response from the server and by forwarding cookies using the cookie HTTP header in the request to the server. https://github.com/shamsimam/grpc-java-cookies

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Headers in gRPC are called "Metadata." Clients can only send "headers". Servers can send both "headers" and "trailers."

You want to:

- Use the `google.golang.org/grpc/metadata` package and `metadata.NewOutgoingContext()` to send metadata *from* the client-side.
- Use `grpc.SendHeader()` and `grpc.SetTrailer()` to send metadata *from* the server-side.
- Use the `grpc.Header()` and `grpc.Trailer()` `CallOptions` for receiving the `Metadata` *on* the client-side.
- Use `metadata.FromIncomingContext()` for receiving metadata *on* the server-side.

Comment: The official documentation at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md is really well done.